# The OCR text recognition camera is not launching

Tags: java, android, ocr, text-recognition

I am working with text recognition on OCR in android. The code I have written have no errors at all, and it also install and create the APK successfully, but i do not know where the problem occurs that it stop activity from launching. It do not even show me any error regarding why its not running, if you have any solution to this problem, or if you could possibly run and test it on android studio and find out the error. Below is my code and the stacktrace result. Thank you.

```js
package com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class cam_calculator extends Activity {

    Button back_frm_came;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION = 100;
    private SurfaceView cameraView;
    private TextView textBlockContent;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam_calculator);


        back_frm_came = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_frm_came);
        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        textBlockContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cam_txt_read);
        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Log.w("MainActivity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");
            
        }
            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                Log.d("Main", "receiveDetections");
                final SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (items.size() != 0) {
                    textBlockContent.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                value.append(item.getValue());
                                value.append("\n");
                            }
                            //update text block content to TextView
                            textBlockContent.setText(value.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });





        back_frm_came.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {cam_calculator.this.finish();
            }
        });

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            cam_calculator.this.finish();
        } else {
            cam_calculator.this.finish();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION:{
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraSource.release();
    }
}
```

**Manifest File**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Stacktrace**

```js
08-07 10:00:28.655 15603-15603/? E/Zygote: v2
08-07 10:00:28.655 15603-15603/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10256
08-07 10:00:28.655 15603-15603/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
08-07 10:00:28.657 15603-15603/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
08-07 10:00:28.658 15603-15603/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
08-07 10:00:28.660 15603-15603/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator 
08-07 10:00:28.665 15603-15603/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-07 10:00:28.778 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator-1/lib/arm64
08-07 10:00:28.794 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator, real application class is null.
08-07 10:00:30.055 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator-1/lib/arm64
08-07 10:00:30.429 15603-15793/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-07 10:00:32.212 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-07 10:00:33.046 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
08-07 10:00:33.047 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
08-07 10:00:34.118 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
08-07 10:00:34.129 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
08-07 10:00:34.129 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101
08-07 10:00:34.140 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
08-07 10:00:34.163 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000c/n/arm64-v8a
08-07 10:00:34.235 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
08-07 10:00:34.243 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: true
08-07 10:00:34.244 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Reading ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
08-07 10:00:34.245 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: jni_helper.cc:76 Loading model config /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models/mognet_lstm_engine_0.7.bincfg
08-07 10:00:34.247 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (detector): 0.215 ms (elapsed)
08-07 10:00:34.253 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: mognet_classifier_client.cc:1810 Using full specialization.
08-07 10:00:34.254 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (classifier): 6.963 ms (elapsed)
08-07 10:00:34.281 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (recognizer): 27.017 ms (elapsed)
08-07 10:00:34.281 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/native: timer.h:126 void ocr::photo::PhotoOcrEngine::Init(): 34.511 ms (elapsed)
08-07 10:00:36.481 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
08-07 10:00:36.491 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
08-07 10:00:36.491 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101
08-07 10:00:36.499 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
08-07 10:00:36.500 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: true
08-07 10:00:36.500 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Reading ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
08-07 10:00:37.619 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-07 10:00:38.473 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-07 10:00:39.869 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
08-07 10:00:39.872 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
08-07 10:00:39.872 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101
08-07 10:00:39.877 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
08-07 10:00:39.877 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: true
08-07 10:00:39.878 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Reading ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
08-07 10:00:50.454 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
08-07 10:00:50.460 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
08-07 10:00:50.460 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101
08-07 10:00:50.465 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
08-07 10:00:50.465 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: true
08-07 10:00:50.465 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Reading ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
08-07 10:02:32.208 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
08-07 10:02:32.213 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
08-07 10:02:32.213 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1101
08-07 10:02:32.218 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
08-07 10:02:32.218 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: true
08-07 10:02:32.218 15603-15603/com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator I/Vision: Reading ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
```

**Gradle Dependencies**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nadeemahmad.smartcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.fathzer', name: 'javaluator', version: '3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```